# Save iterations of for loop in R

Tags: r

I'm working on a project where I need to collect the intercept, slope, and R squared of several linear regressions. Since I need to at least 200 samples of different sample sizes I set-up the code below, but it only saves the last iteration of the loop. Any suggestions on how I can record each loop so that I can have all of the coefficients and r-squares that I require.

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  x <- as.data.frame(mydf[sample(1:1000,25,replace=FALSE),])
  mylm <- lm(spd66305~spd66561, data=x) 
  coefs <- rbind(lman(mylm))
  total.coefs <- rbind(coefs)
}
total.coefs
```

The function used in the loop is below if that is needed.

```
lman <- function(mylm){
  r2 <- summary(mylm)$r.squared
  r <- sqrt(r2)
  intercept <- coef(mylm)[1]
  slope <- coef(mylm)[2]
  tbl <- c(intercept,slope,r2,r)
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: First things first. Your function lman does not output anything and as such it makes little sense to rbind results from that function. Second, the total.coefs is replaced and not updated at each iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before starting your loop, you can write
`total.coefs <- data.frame()`, to initialise an empty data.frame. Then in your loop you want to update the total.coefs, as follows: `total.coefs <- rbind(total.coefs, coefs)`. Finally replace the last line in `lman` by:
`tbl <- data.frame(intercept=intercept, slope=slope, r2=r2, r=r)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it, for example on the `mtcars` data.  Note:  It's not advisable to use `rbind` inside the loop if you're building a data structure.  You can call `rbind` after the looping has been done and things are much less stressful.  I prefer to do this type of operation with a list.

Here I wrapped my `lapply` loop with `rbind`, and then `do.call` binds the list elements together recursively.  Another thing to note is that I take the samples prior to entering the loop. This makes debugging easier and can be more efficient overall

```
reps <- replicate(3, sample(nrow(mtcars), 5), simplify = FALSE)
do.call(rbind, lapply(reps, function(x) {
    mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars[x,])
    c(coef(mod), R = summary(mod)$r.squared)
}))
#      (Intercept)          hp         R
# [1,]    33.29360 -0.08467169 0.5246208
# [2,]    29.97636 -0.06043852 0.4770310
# [3,]    28.33462 -0.05113847 0.8514720
```

The following transposed `vapply` loop produces the same result, and is often faster when you know the type of result you expect

```
t(vapply(reps, function(x) {
    mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars[x,])
    c(coef(mod), R = summary(mod)$r.squared)
}, numeric(3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to record each loop would be to make the work reproducible and keep your datasets around in case you have extreme values, missing values, new questions about the datasets, or other surprises that need investigated.

This is a similar case using the iris dataset.

```
# create sample data
data(iris)
iris <- iris[ ,c('Sepal.Length','Petal.Length')]

# your function with data.frame fix on last line
lman <- function(mylm){
  r2 <- summary(mylm)$r.squared
  r <- sqrt(r2)
  intercept <- coef(mylm)[1]
  slope <- coef(mylm)[2]
  data.frame(intercept,slope,r2,r)
}

# set seed to make reproducible
set.seed(3)

# create all datasets
alldatasets <- lapply(1:200,function(x,df){
  df[sample(1:nrow(df),size = 50,replace = F), ]
},df = iris)

# create all models based on alldatasets
allmodels <- lapply(alldatasets,lm,formula = Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length)

# run custom function on all models
lmanresult <- lapply(allmodels,lman)

# format results
result <- do.call('rbind',lmanresult)
row.names(result) <- NULL

# inspect the 129th sample, model, and result
alldatasets[[129]]
summary(allmodels[[129]])
result[129, ]
```